# CouchDB best pratice for update related documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, nosql, couchdb, updates

I am using *CouchDB* and *NodeJs* with these document examples.

```js
Role {
  _id,
  name
}

User {
  _id,
  email,
  password,
  role: {
    _id,
    name
  }
}
```

What is the best practice to update a *Role* and also do it inside User when _id of the *Roles* are the same.

This is just one example, in the application we will have multiple cases of duplicated documents in differents parts of the database, and we'll need this kind of update to avoid inconsistencies.

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you will try to nest your relations as much as possible.

However, if you need one-to-many or many-to-many relations, you have two options.

## 1) Link with the _Id

This approach is pretty much the same as you would do in SQL. It requires you to do multiple queries (Note: You can emit related document in a view).

It's easy to update (you only update the related document). Altought, it's slower to fetch.

## 2) Duplicate data

The other approach is to duplicate the data everywhere. If you want to link a role to another user, you duplicate that role in the user.

This approach is faster on read but way more complicated on update. 
To update, you need to update the role and also update each duplicated roles.